# Frobenius norm of product of matrix and vector

Tags: normed-spaces, matrix-calculus

I need to find the condition for $\|Ax\|_F^2$=$\|A\|_F^2$$\|x\|_F^2$, where **A** is a matrix and **x** is a vector.
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Frobenius norm is unitarily invariant, i.e. $\|U A V\|_F = \|A\|_F$, for any $U$ and $V$ unitary. So we may assume that $A = \text{diag}(d_1, d_2, \cdots, d_n)$ is diagonal. (The left hand side can be rewritten as $\|U D V^\dagger (V y)\|_F$, where $UDV^\dagger$ is the singular value decomposition of $A$ and $y = V^\dagger x$). Letting $y = (y_1, y_2, \cdots, y_n)^T$, we have
$$\|UDV (Vy)\|_F^2 = \|D y\|_F^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n |d_i y_i|^2$$
We want this value to equal $\|A\|_F^2 \|x\|_F^2 = \|D\|_F^2 \|y\|_F^2$, namely we want
$$\sum_{i = 1}^n |d_i y_i|^2 = \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n |d_i|^2 \right) \left(\sum_{i = 1}^n |y_i|^2 \right)$$
For equality to hold we must have
$$\sum_{i \neq j} |d_i|^2 |y_j|^2 = 0$$
As all terms in the summation are non-negative, we must have each term be zero. So ultimately, we can either have $D = 0$ (implying $A = 0$) or $y = 0$, or have exactly one index $i$ such that $d_i, y_i \neq 0$. So in summary, the equality holds if and only if one of the following is true:

1. $A = 0$
2. $y = 0$
3. $A$ is a rank one matrix (i.e. its singular values are all zero except one, say $d_1$) and $y_1$ is a multiple of the right-singular vector corresponding to the nonzero singular value. An example is
   $$A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0 \\ \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots \\ 0 & 0 & \cdots & 0\end{bmatrix}, ~~ x = \begin{bmatrix} 1 \\ 0 \\ \vdots \\ 0\end{bmatrix}$$

We can also conclude from our steps that in all other cases, we have $\|A x\|_F^2 < \|A \|_F^2 \|x\|_F^2$ (the Frobenius norm is sub-multiplicative).

**Addendum:** Why must $y$ be a right-singular vector?

**Answer:** If we order the singular values (all of which are zero except one) of $A$ in descending order, i.e. $D = \text{diag}(d_1, \cdots, d_n)$ with $d_1 > 0$ and $d_2 = d_3 = \cdots = d_n = 0$, then we want $V^\dagger y = x = \hat{e}_1$ (here $\hat{e}_1$ is the first standard basis vector). Thus $y = V \hat{e}_1$ (which picks out the first column of $V$). This is the definition of the right-singular vector corresponding to the nonzero singular value (the columns of $V$ are the right-singular vectors of $A$).

Comment: Thank you. Could you please detail the why ||Ax||_F = ||UDV'(Vy||_F? Thank you

Comment: Is the following correct? $$\|UDV^\dagger (Vy)\|_F^2 = \|D y\|_F^2$$ Not completely clear how the equality holds then. I see that V is singular, and therefore $$V V^\dagger = I$$

Comment: Thank you. I understand the numerical example you provided. But shouldn't the equality with norms hold true for any matrix A with rank(A) = 1, and any vector x, where x is the right eigenvector corresponding to the highest eigenvalue of A? For example $$ A =
\begin{bmatrix} 
1 & 2 & 3 \\
1 & 2 & 3\\
1 & 2 & 3 \\
\end{bmatrix}
\quad
$$ and $x=[-0.26, -0.15, -0.95]$ (eigenvector corresponding to eigenvalue 6)

Comment: Yes, that is what you have written. But when I numerically check if the equality holds for matrix A, with highest eigenvalue 6, and corresponding eigenvector (-0.5774, -0.5774, -0.5774), I obtain 36 (left side) and 42 (right side) of the equality. I do not understand where is my mistake. Thank you

Comment: Thank you. This works. Is this condition on the right singular vector visible in the proof you provided above? I can't spot it myself. Can you please help me? Thanks

Comment: Thank you! This really helps a lot!

Comment: Very happy to do so. I am new, not sure how to do that. I believe I have marked the answer as "useful". Whatelse can I do?

Comment: Thanks, I should have accepted right now.